# Default props value in a subtype in React

Tags: reactjs

we can have `dafaultProps` for the interface used in Component class in React. I need to provide a default property in a `subtype` which is used in a `prop` defined. 
There is no separated Component defined for this `subtype`

```
export interface TabDetails{
    TabTitle? :string|undefined, 
    Visibility?: boolean,
    tabId: string
}
export interface IDynamicTabs{
    Tabs : TabDetails[],
    onTabVisibilityChanged: (tabId:string, visibility:boolean) => void,
    Max : number
}

public class Dynamictabs extends React.Component<IDynamicTabs>

    public static defaultProps = {
         Max : 5,
        // Tabs.Visibility: true // How to define default value?    
    }
    render(){

    }
}
```

In above I can have defaultProps value for `Max` but how to define value for `TabDetails.Visibility`?

Comment: In React, Default props are only shallowly merged.

Answer (score 1):

This is done through Props default:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

[...]

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  cityList: [],
  provinceList: [],
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  userInfo: PropTypes.object,
  cityList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  provinceList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: I've always wondered: should I add `isRequired` to props that are set through `defaultProps` anyway? It doesn't seem to make a difference. What do you think?

Comment: This is only an example, in real word a prop should be required or be defined as defaultProp

Comment: My question is regarding a subProps (property of another property). In above example, need to set a default property `Tabs.Visibility: true`.